# javascript, play url, onStartPlaying callback

Tags: javascript, audio

I play some audio file:

```
var audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
audio.play();
```

After start playing a need to send some ajax request.
How i can get callback onStartPlaying from audio class?

something like:

```
callback = function ( ){
   ...ajax...
}
audio.onstartplaying = callback;
```

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

To use howler.js library. 
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js

```
var sound = new Howl({
  urls: ['sound.mp3', 'sound.ogg', 'sound.wav'],
  autoplay: true,
  loop: false,
  volume: 0.5,
  onplay: function() {
    console.log('On Play Callback');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HEAD HTML:

```
<script src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
```

BODY HTML:

```
<span id="textbox">click the play button</span><br><br>

<audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeText(newtext) {
    var span = document.getElementById('textbox');
    while( span.firstChild ) span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
    span.appendChild( document.createTextNode(newtext) );
}

audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    var player = audiojs.create( audios[0], {
        play: function() {
            changeText("Audio is Playing"); // change text to "Audio is Playing"
        },
        pause: function() {
            changeText("Audio is Paused"); // change text to "Audio is Paused"
        }
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: [View Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/01p6qf79/2/)